# Sticky hover state in chrome on buttons

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, hover

I have a problem with the hover state in Chrome. There are a couple of bagdes on my site ... when I remove one of them, the next badge remains hovered ... even if I am not hovering with my mouse (same on mobile touch device (but in FF (is it using chrome engine?))). FF and Safari on desktop works fine.

Same Question [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/49473988?hl=en).

Couldnt find any solution yet. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we found a solution to that problem. Simply modified the onClick ... the problem was the focus -> [.blur() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/blur)

before:

```
onClick={onRemove}
```

after

```
onClick={(event) => {event.currentTarget.blur() onRemove()}}
```

Comment: This doesn't work on Chrome Windows.